# Messaging indicator does not obey applications-blacklist

Tags: messaging-menu

Since upgrading from 11.10 to 12.04, the microblogging and instant messaging entries have reappeared in the messaging menu.

I put symlinks in `~/.config/indicators/messages/applications-blacklist` to deactivate `empathy`  `evolution`  `gwibber.indicator`  `ubuntuone-control-panel`, but this does not seem to have any effect now.

How can I remove these entries? I would like to remove the status entries as well, and keep only Thunderbird information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Configuration Editor** to disable notifications where this option is available. For example:

1. To disable **Empathy** notifications : uncheck `/apps/empathy/notifications/notifications_enabled`.
2. To disable **Gwibber** notifications : uncheck `/apps/gwibber/preferences/show_notifications`.